# How to update this textview with the Date every second

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin

```
resultLabel.text = "${SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd hh:mm").format(Date())}"
```

This code is working but I don't know how yu can update `resultLabel.text` every second .

How could I get update time and date like clock in Kotlin?

Comment: Use [Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can update your value using `Timer` class.

```
val timer = Timer()
timer?.scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
    override fun run() {
        updateTimer()
    }
}, 0, 1000)


private fun updateTimer() {
    runOnUiThread {
        resultLabel.text = "${SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd hh:mm").format(Date())}"
    }
}
```

Here is method to stop Time.

```
private fun stopTimer() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer?.cancel()
            timer?.purge()
            timer = null
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to update textview every second

Handler handler = new Handler();

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        tv.append("Hello World");
        resultLabel.text = "${SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd hh:mm").format(Date())}"
    }
};
```

**Call this to start updating textview every second**

```
handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```